# HTTP POST request responds differently in Alamofire than in Jsoup

Tags: ios, swift, jsoup, alamofire

I've been designing a client to display data off a website, that is locked behind a login screen. 
I have been sniffing what headers and parameters are being passed upon the login POST request, and have been able to produce code that sucessfully replicates this login in Jsoup, passing the appropriate headers and parameters.
Passing the exact same headers and parameters in Alamofire, however, makes the website respond with an error message stating that the service is unusable for clients that do not allow 'per-session cookies'. Also the secret key used to access other regions of the website is not present in the response.

**functional Jsoup code**

```
response = Jsoup.connect("URL OF LOGINPAGE")
    .header("Accept ", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
    .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
    .header("Host","www.lectio.dk")
    .header("Referer","URL OF LOGINPAGE; ARBITRARY")
    .header("Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=" + String(SessionId) + ";")
    .data("__EVENTARGUMENT","")
    .data("__EVENTTARGET","m$Content$submitbtn2")
    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION",EventValidation)
    .data("__SCROLLPOSITION","")
    .data("__VIEWSTATE","")
    .data("__VIEWSTATEX",ViewStateX)
    .data("__VIEWSTATEY_KEY", "")
    .data("LectioPostbackId","")
    .data("m$Content$passwordHidden","(password)")
    .data("m$Content$username2", "(username)")
    .data("time", "0").method(Method.POST).execute();
```

**Not so functional Alamofire code**

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                                "Host": "www.lectio.dk",
                                "Referer": "https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/\(schoolNo)/login.aspx",
                                "Cookie" : "ASP.NET_SessionId=" + sessionID + ";"]

    let parameters: Parameters = ["__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
                            "__EVENTTARGET":"m$Content$submitbtn2",
                            "__EVENTVALIDATION" : eventValidation,
                            "__SCROLLPOSITION":"",
                            "__VIEWSTATE":"",
                            "__VIEWSTATEX":viewStateX,
                            "__VIEWSTATEY_KEY" : "",
                            "LectioPostBackId":"",
                            "m$Content$passwordHidden":password,
                            "m$Content$username2":username,
                            "time":"0"]

    Alamofire.request("URL OF LOGIN PAGE", method: .post, parameters:parameters, headers: headers).responseString { response in ...
```

**How the website handles authentication**

Upon passing a GET request, a few important values are passed back. Namely a SessionId that is used later. This is stored for later usage in the POST request.

When the login button is clicked, aforementioned values are passed as headers or parameters, including username and password. Upon sucessful authentication, a special key is returned, and the user is referred to the main page.

Now, using Jsoup, the authentication works flawlessly and the parsed response is the correct main page on which the user is logged in. - I guess that this would indicate that Jsoup automatically follows the referral and sends the appropriate headers and parameters?

In Alamofire, the Authentication is unsuccesful, resulting in the error message mentioned above.

Since headers and params are the same, I guess the issue lies in the way Alamofire and jsoup handles requests. The content-type for the post is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Alamofire defaults to something else I believe, but the documentation states nothing about changing this default per alamofire version 4. (It had this encoding feature in version 3, according to the migration guide?)

I'm not sure where to go from here. any help much appreciated
-Sam

Comment: Set the user-agent string of both of your apps to be the same as the browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like cookies are handled differently. It seems like the response of the initial GET request contains a cookie, that the server expects in the following POST request. It would appear that Jsoup automatically sends received cookies in subsequent requests, but Alamofire doesn‘t. This would explain the server complaining about missing support of „per-session cookies“. For the Alamofire approach, try reading the cookies from the response to the initial GET request and explicitly set them for the subsequent requests.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am passing all the necessary headers ( and therefore cookies) in the POST request, therefore making me confused as to why I am not receiving my special key. All cookies should be correctly set, which is why I suspect a higher level protocol difference in the two libraries to be the culprit. If only I could find it.

Comment: @SamuelGrund See my additional answer for further details.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter encoding is the problem: you can change it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`in your Alamofire request with

`Alamofire.request("{URL}", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)`

(see https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#parameter-encoding)

Now that i see your code and after further investigation, i think that Alamofire actually does handle the sending of cookies automatically (see [Does Alamofire store the cookies automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025110/does-alamofire-store-the-cookies-automatically)) and Jsoup does not and therefore, the cookie header, that you set explicitly, is overwritten by some Alamofire-internal cookie handling. Try to disable the automatic setting of cookie headers by adding

`Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.httpShouldSetCookies = false`

before you execute the request.

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately to no avail. Also, adding the encoding parameter in the request leads to error: "Extra argument 'method' in call".

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem recently. I send POST request and I received GET in server.
I found that it was caused by wrong format of url address.

I was sending POST request on "https://webpage.com/post". I overlooked, that I get 301 as response and I was redirected to "https://www.webpage.com/post".
Redirection changed type of request.

I only change format of url to "https://www.webpage.com/post" and it start to work.